# Get webpage text from URL after authorization

Tags: python, authorization, python-requests

I need to get the output printed on the screen on accessing a url with username and password. When I access the url through my browser, I get a popup where I enter the credentials and get the output in the browser. How do I do it using python script? I tried the following, but it only returns `<Response [200]>` which means that the request is successful. The output I want is a simple text message.

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
print response
```

I have tried `requests.post` also, with same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print response` tries to print out a Response object. If you want the text of the response, use `print response.text`.

You may want to read the Quickstart documentation for the python-requests library here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/.